# Select all products with prices in EAV scheme

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

It's a generic SQL question. I have a query that selects all rows from the Products with extra information from other tables. The problem is that it's EAV scheme and the last relation is somehow reversed and joins break.

The requirements are:

- list all Products with Groups
- if 'Price' in Values table is available, add this information
- explicitly: if 'Price' is not available, there should be Product row without Price information
- Products can't be repeated
- Additionally: DISTINCT is out of question

I have a working query (below) that uses a subquery to filter values, but I need to get rid of it. I can only uses joins.

[SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0576b/8](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0576b/8)

```
create table Products (
    id int primary key,
    groupId int,
    code varchar(100)
);

create table Groups (
    id int primary key,
    code varchar(100)
);

create table Values (
    id int primary key,
    productId int,
    typeId int,
    value varchar(100)
);

create table ValueTypes (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(100)
);

insert into Products values (1, 1, 'P1');
insert into Products values (2, 2, 'P2');
insert into Groups values (1, 'C1');
insert into Groups values (2, 'C2');
insert into Values values (1, 1, 1, 'Aqua');
insert into Values values (2, 1, 2, '$5');
insert into ValueTypes values (1, 'Name');
insert into ValueTypes values (2, 'Price');
```

My query that works:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN Groups g ON p.groupId = g.id
LEFT JOIN Values v ON v.productId = p.id AND v.typeId = (SELECT id FROM ValueTypes WHERE name = 'Price')
```

The question is, how to rewrite it to use joins instead of subquery?

I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN Groups g ON p.groupId = g.id
LEFT JOIN Values v ON v.productId = p.id
LEFT JOIN ValueTypes vt ON vt.id = v.typeId AND vt.name = 'Price'
```

But it returns repeated product P1. INNER JOIN on the other hand omits Products without a 'Price' value.

Comment: is this sql server  ?,plus 1 for the data

Comment: PostgreSQL, but it shouldn't matter for the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define JOIN order explicitly

```
SELECT *
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN Groups g ON p.groupId = g.id
LEFT JOIN (  --product price
  SELECT productId, value  
  FROM Values v2
  JOIN ValueTypes vt ON vt.id = v2.typeId AND vt.name = 'Price'
) v ON v.productId = p.id;
```

**EDIT**
2 more JOIN versions. Optimizer produces different plan as compared to above version

```
SELECT *
FROM ValueTypes vt
INNER JOIN Products p ON vt.name = 'Price'
INNER JOIN Groups g ON p.groupId = g.id
LEFT JOIN Values v ON v.productId = p.id AND v.typeId = vt.id;
```

or slightly different v3

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id FROM ValueTypes WHERE name = 'Price') vt
CROSS JOIN Products p 
INNER JOIN Groups g ON p.groupId = g.id
LEFT JOIN Values v ON v.productId = p.id AND v.typeId = vt.id
```

Comment: Do you expect it to be faster than my subquery? Gonna check tomorrow ;)

Comment: It seems to be a bit slower than my query with subquery. My nominal time is 12,5 s +- 5%; your JOIN on subquery gives 13s + 20%. But I guess there could be scenarios where this construct is better.

Comment: I think subquery is quite at right place. If you need only JOIN query nevertheless , see more options, edited.

Comment: The version with FROM that starts with ValueTypes wins :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do as this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.code, g.id, g.code, 
       max(case when vt.name='Price' 
                then v.value
                else null end) as price
  FROM Products p
       LEFT JOIN Groups g ON p.groupId = g.id
       LEFT JOIN Values v ON v.productId = p.id 
       LEFT join ValueTypes vt ON v.typeId = vt.id
  group by p.id, p.code, g.id, g.code
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0576b/36

Comment: Numer of rows returned is ok, but (1) 'Price' is not a number, so I have only NULLs returned; (2) this query is so slow, about almost 180% slower (30 seconds)

Comment: 1 - Its is not Price I'm returning on the query it is `v.value` as per your requirement `explicitly: if 'Price' is not available, there should be Product row without Price information` 2- It shouldn't be that slow, to analyze such thing I would like to see an explain plan of the query, so I could suggest some indexes OR you could show the tables structure with defined indexes. If it is that slow it means that you don't have a setup with proper indexes on your tables.

Comment: Again, v.value is not a number :) And it's slow because of grouping, my query uses the same tables and joins. The same with Serg's answer.

Comment: Now I understand why are you saying this ` v.value is not a number` the aggregation function `max` does not need the value passed to it to be a number, it is just a technique to take out duplicated results when one of then are null which is your case. Simple joins like this should not be excessive slow as you said. It will depend on the indexes you have as I mentioned on earlier comments. But ok. You have already accepted the other answer :)

Comment: "max does not need the value passed to it to be a number" - I didn't know that. But when I run the query you wrote I receive only empty values for the price.

Comment: That's odd, would you add these missing data on sqlfiddle (the one I used on my answer) so I could check? I'm saying that it is odd because of the working sample on fiddle.

Comment: Great then. What about the time? Still slow?